# Preserve resolution of image on bitmap compression

Tags: java, android, image, compression, resolution

On my apps, I load every drawable and I save it on phone memory, but when I do this process, all drawable change to a big resolution :

Before Compress: 
FileA.PNG on drawable : 423x101 ; 9,52Ko

After Compress : 
FileA.PNG on SD Card : 1269x303 ; 89,36Ko

Do you know how to keep the ( Before ) resolution after compress ?
I try with JPEG but same result.

```
public void SaveImage(int resId){

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);

    try {

        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Folder", getResources().getResourceEntryName(resId)+".PNG");
        file.createNewFile();
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

If you can give me a clue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store images in the `drawable` folder, they gets scaled automatically according to your device's resolution, hence making different size.

You will need to store them in the folder `drawable-nodpi`, or somewhere in `raw` or `assets`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the anwser, the "nodpi" folder was the solution :), thanks again !

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a drawable and convert it to a Bitmap you get every pixel encoded and that's a bigger file that the original PNG. If you then save the PNG at 100% quality that's still a large image.

Set the quality much lower:

```
 bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 20, fOut);
```

Play with the quality until you get a result you like.